# Get thumbnail image of PDF using ASP.NET?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, asp.net-3.5, thumbnails

I have a system where users can upload PDF documents. Rather than displaying the link to these PDFs as a title link, or a PDF icon link, I would like it to be a thumbnail of the first page of the PDF document.

How can I get a thumbnail image of the first (or any specified) page of a PDF document, using ASP.NET 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a free component to display PDF thumbnails in asp.net: http://www.tallcomponents.com/pdfthumbnail-versions.aspx

[GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com) is another option.

Answer (score 0):

There are no built in PDF capabilities in the BCL.

You will need to use a PDF library that allows you to output images. Use it to render the first page as a thumbnail.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/pdfthumbnail.aspx) is one article on code project to do this (using acrobat and COM interop), [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/447b4310-2d9f-4307-b648-775f6d091ab1/) a thread on MSDN forums .